# How to dynamically check/uncheck html checkbox by JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

[image]I know that several questions about this topic have been asked, but I was unable to find an answer for my case.

I have gridview. In that Checkbox.

Here, I want to do functionality like When I check on exp_id 1515001101 then others all exp_id 1515001101 get automatically check.
[image]

```
     function checkUncheckHeaderCheckBoxforSubmit(obj)
 {var checkboxCell;var expidCell;

          var grid = document.getElementById("<%=grdViewLocalConvence.ClientID %>"); 
for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length - 2; i++)

    { for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length - 2; i++) 
{ checkboxCell = grid.rows[i].cells[8];
           expidCell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];

          var exp_id = expidCell.innerText;
        for (j = 0; j < checkboxCell.childNodes.length; j++) 
    {if (checkboxCell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") 
    {  if (checkboxCell.childNodes[j].checked == true)
     { var exp_id = expidCell.innerText;  
                          GridVwHeaderChckbox.rows[i].cells[8].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked = 
    exp_id.checked;
          }}}}
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is you r code ? What did you tried ?

Comment: did you try $('.checkboxid').attr('checked', true);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(".checkboxid").change(function() {// the first checking checkbox
        if(this.checked) {
            $('.checkboxid').attr('checked', true);// here put change checkbox details that are checked automatically
        }
    });
```

If you want to fix the state of these check boxes remains same then best idea is  save data to db and retrieve each time the page load happends

Comment: It is not working. Actullay I am using for in loop 
var arry=['1515001161','1515001161','1515001107','1515001106' ]
 for (exp_id in arry) {
grid.rows[i].cells[8].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked = true;
}

Here when I click on first id 1515001161 then It will automatically check all other checkboxes with same id 1515001161.

Comment: what do you mean by same id ? same id for more than one checkbox ?

Comment: Yes. Same id for more than one checkbox.